# Getting Pandas error while exporting data to excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Getting pandas error as: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,2)

Trying to export details in excel, i tried with below code:

Expected output:
selected customer names: name1, name2 for the desig: CUST
selected customer names: values name3, name4 for the desig :ORDER

Have tried below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

def CUST1(): 
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['CUST', 'name1', 'PIZZA', 'A'],
    ['CUST', 'name2', 'DONUT', 'A'],
    ['ORDER', 'name3', 'CAKE','B'],
    ['ORDER', 'name4', 'COOKIES', 'C']
    ],
    columns=("DESIG", "NAMES", "CITIES", "CLASS"))
    ORD = pd.concat((df['DESIG'],df.groupby('DESIG') 
    ['NAMES'].transform(lambda x: ", ".join(x))), 
    axis=1).drop_duplicates()
    print(ORD)
    for x, name in enumerate(ORD):
     worksheet1.write(x, 0, "selected customer names" 
     + df['DESIG'] + "for" +df.groupby('DESIG') 
     ['NAMES'])
CUST1()
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want according to the expected output provided. I just utilized the dataFrame ORD since it contains all the necessary information without having to do more data transformations.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

def CUST1(): 
    df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['CUST', 'name1', 'PIZZA', 'A'],
    ['CUST', 'name2', 'DONUT', 'A'],
    ['ORDER', 'name3', 'CAKE','B'],
    ['ORDER', 'name4', 'COOKIES', 'C']
    ],
    columns=("DESIG", "NAMES", "CITIES", "CLASS"))
    ORD = pd.concat((df['DESIG'],df.groupby('DESIG') 
    ['NAMES'].transform(lambda x: ", ".join(x))), 
    axis=1).drop_duplicates()

    for x in range(len(ORD)):
        worksheet1.write_string(x, 0, "selected customer names: " 
         + ORD['NAMES'].iloc[x] + " for the desig: " +  ORD['DESIG'].iloc[x])
CUST1()
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you...is there any way that we can do this with out numpy?

Comment: Yes! I edited so now there is no numpy. There are many ways to answer this problem!

Comment: Excellent, thanks alot @Kasper....I dont know we can use like this: ORD['NAMES'].iloc[x]....Thanks alot

Comment: @GeethaAnand Pandas is Numpy on steroids (it's a Numpy wrapper AFAIK)